# How to get text until a symbol in string

Tags: c#, string

How to get text before a symbol in string ? Any ideas?

e.g. `acsbkjb/123kbvh/123jh/`

get text before first  - "/"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the required part of the string.

```
String text="acsbkjb/123kbvh/123jh/";
int index=text.IndexOf('/');  
String text2="";

if(index>=0)
text2=text.Substring(0,index);
```

Comment: OP didn't specify whether an input string can have no forwards at all (in which case this would throw an exception), but it's the correct solution for the validated input.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
string ss = myString.Split('/')[0];
```

Comment: This is not a good answer since the OP asked for the text before the first '/'. I understand your code does the job, but it is not efficient in comparison to the IndexOf method.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, there are no edits and Sachin answer does the right thing (maybe not in a right way). Think wide. What if OP's next question would be "and how to get the text before next backslash"? Then suddenly `IndexOf` become not so efficient. More answers = better.

Comment: @Sinatr: That is true, but I wanted to point out that this is not the most efficient answer, especially since this answer is upvoted a lot.

Comment: Note: This will still return all the characters even when there is no `/` character. That may not be the desired behavior

Answer (score 3):

get substring like

```
youstring.Substring(0,yourstring.IndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 3):

The IEnumerable approach

```
  string str = "acsbkjb/123kbvh/123jh/";
  var result = new string(str.TakeWhile(a => a != '/').ToArray());
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If there are no forward slashes this works without need to check the return of IndexOf

**EDIT** Keep this answer just as an example because the efficiency of this approach is really worse. IndexOf works faster also if you add an if statement to check the return value.

Comment: It's good that it works even if there are no forward slashes, but, as you mentioned, it's not the most efficient way to do it due to the characters being copied twice.

Comment: @Groo tested a bit and the efficiency is really abysmal, I am tempted to remove the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "acsbkjb/123kbvh/123jh/";    
string text2 = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf("/"));
```